# ubuntu 13.10 booting problem

Tags: boot

On fresh Ubuntu 13.10 installation, on boot it shows black screen with error message.

How can I fix this?

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/f8d8eb7d-2423-4cc5-b0e6-72d47678121e does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `exit` at the prompt and the system should boot.
After that  edit your `/boot/grub/menu.lst` to wait longer for the root device. Add `rootdelay=XXX` parameter, or adjust it to a bigger value.